# jshint no error for forin (hasOwnProperty)

Tags: jslint, jshint, hasownproperty

Why jshint is not reporting forin (hasOwnProperty) error for the following code? jslint do report error on it but jshint doesn't.

```
/*jshint forin: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}, i = null;

    for (i in obj) {
        if (i === 0) {
            console.log('blah...');
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant snippet of code from JSHint (modified slightly for formatting):

```
if (
    state.option.forin && 
    s && 
    (s.length > 1 || typeof s[0] !== "object" || s[0].value !== "if")
) {
    warning("W089", this);
}
```

The important part is `s[0].value !== "if"`. JSHint won't raise an error if the first statement of the `for...in` body is an `if` statement, regardless of the condition of that statement.

Comment: Oh I see! It's not a bug, it's by design. Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Good call. Just to round out why JSLint *does* work, [JSLint's current code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/c657984cd7dfc17277feadb86d1de24c664f944a/jslint.js) has that explicit check for `hasOwnProperty` for the `if` after the `for` (rather than JSHint's only checking for the `if`) at the `case` block that starts line 3687.